# R GAM visualisation - Negative Binomial

Tags: r, gam

This is a follow on question from my question answered by previously for a generic gaussian GAM model in R. This time I tried running a negative binomial GAM with the same dataset and I have attached the plot below. I am not sure if it is plotting what I want it to, as it is showing both two error intervals instead of how the previous GAM showed just the modelled error interval. [[image: Negative Binomial GAM plot].

```
mod_gam3 <-gam(y ~s(ï..x), data=Bird.data, family=nb, method="REML)

mod_gam3$fitted.values
result <-data.frame(data = c(mod_gam3$fitted.values, Bird.data$y), 
Year =rep(1991:2019, times ``= 2), 'source' = c(rep('Modelled', times = 29),
rep('Observed', times = 29)))
result$se=c(predict(mod_gam3, se=T)$se, rep(NA,29))

ggplot(result, aes(x=Year, y =data, colour= source, fill=source))+
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(aes(ymin=data-1.96*se, ymax=+1.96*se), alpha=0.2)+
labs(x="Year", y ="Bird Island Total Debris Count")+
scale_y_continous(limits =c(-200,1000))
```

Comment: I think you mean to use geom_ribbon here instead of geom_smooth

Answer (score 1):

There seem to a number of typos in your code above.

I think best to pass your data directly to `ggplot`, and specify within the `geom_smooth()` function, the method, the formula, and the method.args.

```
ggplot(Bird.data, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="gam", formula=y~s(x), method.args=list(family="nb", method="REML"))
```

[image: gam_nb_smooth]

Update: if you want to approximate the plot that you get from the direct method, above, but this time adding markers for the actual predicted data points at the same points where you have data, you can estimate ymin and ymax directly, and then generate the plot like this:

```
mod_gam3 <-gam(y ~s(x), data=Bird.data, family="nb", method="REML")

result <-data.frame(
  data = c(mod_gam3$fitted.values, Bird.data$y),
  Year =rep(1991:2019, times = 2),
  source = c(rep('Modelled', times = 29),
             rep('Observed', times = 29)
             )
  )
result$se=c(predict(mod_gam3, se=T)$se, rep(NA,29))

## set ymin and ymax columns properly
result$ymin = exp(log(result$data)-1.96*result$se)
result$ymax = exp(log(result$data)+1.96*result$se)


ggplot(result, aes(x=Year, y =data, colour= source, fill=source))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = result[result$source=="Modelled",]) +
  geom_ribbon(
    data = result[result$source=="Modelled",],
    aes(x=Year,ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax),alpha=0.2)+
  labs(x="Year", y ="Bird Island Total Debris Count")
```

Comment: Hi langtang, when I tried the second half of the code this warning message appeared: result$ymin = exp(log(result$data)-1.96*result$se)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ymin, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 58

Comment: I'm not sure - I can't replicate your error, so I assume you have an error in your code above where my code starts (i.e. prior to me setting ymin, ymax).  I've updated a bit, but none of the above code changes